# How to get the file name under a folder?

Tags: php, file

Suppose I have a directory look like:

```
ABC
|_ a1.txt
|_ a2.txt
|_ a3.txt
|_ a4.txt
|_ a5.txt
```

How can I use PHP to get these file names to an array, limited to a specific file extension and ignoring directories?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [glob()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function:

**Example 01:**

```
<?php
  // read all files inside the given directory
  // limited to a specific file extension
  $files = glob("./ABC/*.txt");
?>
```

**Example 02:**

```
<?php
  // perform actions for each file found
  foreach (glob("./ABC/*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
  }
?>
```

**Example 03: Using [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)**

```
<?php 
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../")) as $file) {
  if (strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".txt") {
        echo $file;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hrrm...how does that put them into an array?

Comment: i added the top example $files will be the array of txt files paths

Comment: Seems to me that you have an extra ")" after your glob function.

Comment: @Joel absolutely right sir. a whopsie on the copy'n'paste, thanks for point it out :s

Comment: Make sure that you eliminate any directories that glob returns (It should always return the current and parent directories, "." and ".."). Comb the array with `array_filter( $files, 'is_file' );` to eliminate these dirs. Also, glob is very slow. Even though it takes more code, I prefer the `opendir`/`readdir` option.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder glob wont return directorys, only files ending with .txt

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone If the pattern is used correctly, then yes. But glob can still be slow. If you don't care about sorting you can use GLOB_NOSORT as an optional last argument to shave off precious processing time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    $files=array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(is_file($file)){
            $files[]=$file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`scandir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) lists files and directories inside the specified path.

Comment: This includes sub-directories also though...not sure the OP wants that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most **Efficient** way based on this [article](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/)'s benchmarks:

```
function getAllFiles() {
    $files = array();
    $dir = opendir('/ABC/');
    while (($currentFile = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        if (endsWith($currentFile, '.txt'))
            $files[] = $currentFile;
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $files;
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr($haystack, -strlen($needle)) == $needle;
}
```

just use the getAllFiles() function, and you can even modify it to take the folder path and/or the extensions needed, it is easy.

Comment: Hi how will you echo the filenames with that?

Comment: @user3771102 The returned `$files` array contains all file names with their extensions & you can `foreach` & echo them like `foreach($files as $fileName){echo $fileName;}`, or if you just want to prove that it is working, you can echo `$currentFile` inside the inner `if` above

Answer (score 0):

Aside from [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) (@miku), you might also find [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) interesting for wildcard matching.

Answer (score 0):

If your text files is all that you have inside of the folder, the simplest way is to use scandir, like this:

```
<?php
$arr=scandir('ABC/');
?>
```

If you have other files, you should use glob as in Lawrence's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "your folder url"; //give only url, it shows all folder data

if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            if($file != '.' and $file != '..'){
                echo $file .'<br>';
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

output:

```
xyz
abc
2017
motopress
```

Comment: actually, you haven't answered the question asked – in the part "limited to a specific file extension"

Comment: Please give some explanation as to how your answer is supposed to solve the original question.